# Avoid .await in elastic4s query

Tags: scala, playframework, elastic4s

In the elastic4s documentation on the HitReader Typeclass it says that the `.await` should be avoided in production:

```
case class Character(name: String, location: String)

implicit object CharacterHitReader extends HitReader[Character] {
  override def read(hit: Hit): Either[Throwable, Character] = {
    Right(Character(hit.sourceAsMap("name").toString, hit.sourceAsMap("location").toString))
  }
}

val resp = client.execute {
  search("gameofthrones" / "characters").query("kings landing")
}.await // don't block in real code

// .to[Character] will look for an implicit HitReader[Character] in scope
// and then convert all the hits into Characters for us.
val characters :Seq[Character] = resp.to[Character]
```

I would like to take the returned `characters` value and use it to generate a response in my web application(this could be a JSON for instance).

Of course if the .await is simply removed it generates an error that a Future was expected:

```
Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : scala.util.Left[A,B]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Either[com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.RequestFailure,com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.RequestSuccess[com.sksamuel.elastic4s.http.search.SearchResponse]]]
```

So for so good and I understand that I would have to wait with further processing until Elasticsearch has returned a result. 
However, this way the thread is blocked and under high load the JWM crashes from timeouts. 
I would like to free up those resources while Elasicsearch is working on the query.

How can, in general, the returned query values be processed further in a non-blocking manner?

And specifically, how can the `.await` be removed and a non-blocking call created for the server?

Comment: See general introduction: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#functional-composition-and-for-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

I don't us elastic4s. But if you use it together with Play you are fine.

Just map the Future to whatever output you like. Taking the example from here [play-elastic4s](https://github.com/evojam/play-elastic4s):

```
class BookDao @Inject()(
    cs: ClusterSetup,
    elasticFactory: PlayElasticFactory,
    @Named("book") indexAndType: IndexAndType) extends
        ElasticDsl {

    private[this] lazy val client = elasticFactory(cs)

    def searchByAnything(q: String): Future[RichSearchResponse] = client execute {
        search in indexAndType query q
    }
}
```

You can use that like that in your Controller:

```
class HomeController @Inject()(dao: BookDao, myExecutionContext: MyExecutionContext, val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {
  def index = Action.async {
    dao.searchByAnything("your_search")
      .map( Ok(YourJsonEncoder.toJson))
    }(myExecutionContext)
  }
}
```